# Map several pages as large region into process memory space

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-device-driver

I was wondering if there is an api to map multiple seperate pages as one continious region into a processes memory space.
I.e. I allocated two pages a and b with `alloc_pages(fags, 0)` and now want to map them as a memory chunk of the size `2*PAGESIZE` into the memory of `current`. According to LDD3 I can use `remap_pfn_range` to remap seperate pages, however there seems to be no interface to combine multiple pages.

What is the correct way to map multiple pages as one larege region into a processes Memory space?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2: I had different assumptions about the question.**

**With a better understanding, my suggestion is just:**

- Userspace process allocates memory (using `mmap` or such), passes the address range to the kernel OR use `vmalloc()` in kernel to allocate contiguous virtual memory.
- `alloc_pages(...)` to allocate contiguous physical pages
- Get `vm_area_struct` for the allocated memory ranges (allocated via `mmap` or `valloc`)
- `remap_pfn_range()` to map those pages to the allocated contiguous space's `vm_area_struct`. Make sure to use the correct `vm_flags`. For multiple pages, you will need to invoke `remap_pfn_range()` multiple times for each page, and also you will need to change the `addr` offset input parameter each time.

### Old info:

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention this:

Please see: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/cma.c#L212

```
194 /**
195  * cma_declare_contiguous() - reserve custom contiguous area
196  * @base: Base address of the reserved area optional, use 0 for any
197  * @size: Size of the reserved area (in bytes),
198  * @limit: End address of the reserved memory (optional, 0 for any).
199  * @alignment: Alignment for the CMA area, should be power of 2 or zero
200  * @order_per_bit: Order of pages represented by one bit on bitmap.
201  * @fixed: hint about where to place the reserved area
202  * @res_cma: Pointer to store the created cma region.
203  *
204  * This function reserves memory from early allocator. It should be
205  * called by arch specific code once the early allocator (memblock or bootmem)
206  * has been activated and all other subsystems have already allocated/reserved
207  * memory. This function allows to create custom reserved areas.
208  *
209  * If @fixed is true, reserve contiguous area at exactly @base.  If false,
210  * reserve in range from @base to @limit.
211  */
212 int __init cma_declare_contiguous(phys_addr_t base,
213                         phys_addr_t size, phys_addr_t limit,
214                         phys_addr_t alignment, unsigned int order_per_bit,
215                         bool fixed, struct cma **res_cma)
```

You use this to reserve a contiguous area. Once you have the `struct cma`, you can use `cma_alloc()`.

Please see: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/cma.c#L329

This is the `cma_alloc()` function that can be used to allocate contiguous memory in an address space.

```
320 /**
321  * cma_alloc() - allocate pages from contiguous area
322  * @cma:   Contiguous memory region for which the allocation is performed.
323  * @count: Requested number of pages.
324  * @align: Requested alignment of pages (in PAGE_SIZE order).
325  *
326  * This function allocates part of contiguous memory on specific
327  * contiguous memory area.
328  */
329 struct page *cma_alloc(struct cma *cma, int count, unsigned int align)
```

Then you can use `remap_pfn_range()`, as you have mentioned in your question, to remap the memory to a process' address space.

Comment: From what I understand this requires to: a) set a side continious areas at boottime (see Line 204), b) It requires the memory to be in a physically consistent chunk. I want to have the option to either use my memory seperatly as page `a` and page `b` or concatinated as a superpage `ab`. I do not care about physical layout at all. I only need it continious in the process (virtual) memory space. Having it continious in the device address space is a bonus, but that is where `pci_map_sg` comes in.

Comment: seems like I needed longer to skim across `cma.c` than you did, but still my intention stays the same.

Comment: You can use `vmalloc()` then if all you care about is contiguous memory in virtual memory.

Comment: Actually, isn't `alloc_pages` already allocating contiguous pages? I may have misunderstood your question. Why can't you just remap both of your pages into a single contiguous region using remap_pfn_range?

Comment: I try to have a pool, in that pool i have X allocations each returned by `alloc_pages` (at the moment). Now if the user requests memory from the driver the driver should return a memory area of the requested size to the user. To do this I want to take as many allready allocated pages from the pool, until I can match the size and map these into the userprocess. This technique might make it necessary to map several allocations together as one large one. I hope this clarifies my intentions somewhat.

Comment: The reason for this is that I actually want to pin the pages for dma, and don't always want to reallocate and repin pages for the dma region.

Comment: I'm not sure I know if an API that does exactly what you want easy-mode. I think invoking `remap_pfn_range` multiple times (each with a different page-aligned `addr` input parameter) for the `vm_area_struct` for the user's memory space will work.